# Probability confusion - book's answer

Tags: probability

The freshman profile in a university says that 40% of the students were toppers in their high school, and that 65% are white, of whom 25% were toppers in their high school. Probability of selecting a student randomly who was either a topper or is white?

The book stated the answer as: 0.40 + 0.65 - 0.25 = 0.80

Whereas I believe it should be: 0.40 + 0.65 - 0.1625 = 0.8875

The 0.1625 value comes from evaluating 0.25(0.65).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I think the statement

> 65% are white, of whom 25% were toppers

is a little ambiguous, and that's the difference between the two answers.

The book apparently took this to mean: 65% of the students are white ... and 25% of all the students are white and a topper (meaning that 15% of all the students are toppers but not white)

But you interpreted it as: 25% of all the white students are toppers ... meaning that (0.25)(0.65) = 16.25% is a topper and white

Frankly, I would interpret it your way as well! That is certainly a much more natural reading of the sentence. So, I much prefer your answer.

Comment: Good catch on reading the statement in more detail, I had missed that the OP had multiplied $0.65$ and $0.25$ rather than multiplying $0.65$ and $0.4$.  Personally, I read it the same as the book but I can see how you might read it the other way as well.  If we were using raw numbers and we had $100$ students total, saying we have $65$ students who are white, $25$ of which are white and a topper., it would have unambiguously been $Pr(A\cap B)=0.25$.

Comment: This is a good reminder that whenever we use the word *percent*, we really should include the remainder of the statement explaining what it is a percent of.

Comment: @JMoravitz And I did the same thing initially as well! I';m reminded of a commercial from a bank I heard some eyars ago: "Our loan interest rates are 1% lower than our competitors!" .. so if the competitors rate was 10% ... were they at 9%, or at 9.9%?

Comment: I think we would "all" conclude that the modifying clause "of whom ..." makes it "clear"  that 25% of the whites were toppers. But oh well.

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you so much! I thought I had forgotten all of probability after getting such an easy problem wrong haha.

Comment: @user708015 You're welcome! :)